# Disable progress bar advance in Exoplayer progress bar in Android

Tags: android, kotlin, exoplayer, progress

I'm using the Exoplayer library to load videos in my application, but in certain videos I want to avoid that the user can't go forward in the video progress bar, only backward, until now I had achieved something by adding a listener to the DefaultTimeBar in this way:

```kotlin
var currentPosition: Long = 0
val exoPlayerProgressBar: DefaultTimeBar? = localPlayerView?.findViewById(
    R.id.exo_progress
) as? DefaultTimeBar
exoPlayerProgressBar?.addListener(object: TimeBar.OnScrubListener {
    override fun onScrubStart(timeBar: TimeBar, position: Long) {
        currentPosition = position
    }

    override fun onScrubMove(timeBar: TimeBar, position: Long) {
        if (currentPosition < position) {
            timeBar.setPosition(position)
            timeBar.setEnabled(false)
        }
    }

    override fun onScrubStop(timeBar: TimeBar, position: Long, canceled: Boolean) {
        timeBar.setEnabled(true)
    }
})
```

But it doesn't work well at all, I think the listener takes a long time to be called and the position of the onScrubStart method is not exact and besides, although I manage to disable the user to advance, I haven't managed to do it if he clicks on a place on the bar. Is there another way that I don't know?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using custom view for your xml then setting this in xml will work for androidx.media3.ui.DefaultTimeBar

```
app:touch_target_height="0dp"
```

I also got this answer from one of stackoverflow answer only but not having link as of now.

Comment: Is there a way to do it by code? I need it only in some cases.

Comment: You can customize Default timebar to use this property then, this property is in private access currently. You can set through xml only

Answer (score 0):

You should use `ExoPlayer.Listener` and override `onPlaybackStateChanged()` to detect state of playing video progress (`Player.STATE_IDLE`, `Player.STATE_BUFFERING`, `Player.STATE_READY`, `Player.STATE_ENDED`), use `Player.STATE_READY` to hide the progress bar and `Player.STATE_BUFFERING` to show the progress bar.

```
override fun onPlaybackStateChanged(playbackState: Int) {
    when (playbackState) {
        Player.STATE_ENDED -> {}
        Player.STATE_READY -> hideProgressBar() //*Hide progressbar!
        Player.STATE_BUFFERING -> showProgressBar() //*Show progressbar!
        Player.STATE_IDLE -> {}
    }
}
```

[Listening to playback events](https://exoplayer.dev/listening-to-player-events.html#listening-to-playback-events)